# How does one grant apache2 access to files hosted under a secondary partition?

Tags: apache, symlink

I am having an issue with my apache configuration, whereby the web browser throws up a 403: Forbidden error when trying to access a symlinked resource that resides on a secondary partition.

I am aware that there are two key components that need to be in place in order to circumvent a garden-variety 403 error:

1. Symlinks must be enabled in an apache config file. (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`).
2. The apache2 linux user account, `www-data`, must have permissions that are strong enough to let it read, write, execute the files within the symlinked directory, and the directories leading up to said directory.

I have enabled symlinks, but I am having trouble with an aspect of the permissions configuration.

In regards to 1., I am using the following syntax to enable symlinks (and configure the root directory):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have verified that symlinks are working:

I have placed a symlink within `/var/www/`, named `home-apache`, which points to `/home/kohl/kohl/srv/apache`. Within `/home/kohl/kohl/srv/apache`, I have a file named `test.html`. When I visit `localhost/home-apache/test.html`, I can access the file.

In other words, `var/www/home-apache/test.html` is pointing to `/home/kohl/kohl/srv/apache/test.html`, and by virtue of the apache configurating establishing the root at `/var/www`, I can access the webpage by typing `localhost/home-apache/test.html` in the browser.

However, this only works because the actual test.html file resides on the main partition - the same partition as `/var/www`.

If I repeat the test, but simlink the file `/media/kohl/artemis/test/secondary-drive-test.html` to `/var/www/home-apache/secondary-drive-test.html`, and visit `localhost/home-apache/secondary-drive-test.html`, (note that the actual file now resides on the secondary partition, `artemis`) I get a 403.

I believe that this problem is caused by the fact that `www-data` is unable to access '/media/kohl'. I can verify this noting the output of `sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/kohl/`, which is `ls: cannot open directory '/media/kohl/': Permission denied`.

However, attempts to change permissions of the directory, thus rectifying the problem, are futile.

After running `sudo chmod 777 /media/kohl`, and then re-running `sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/kohl/`, I still get the same `Permission denied` message - despite a normal `ls -la` revealing permissions of the /media/kohl directory to be omnilenient - `drwxrwxrwx`. For good measure, I have also added the `kohl` user to the `www-data` group and vice-versa.

I am a bit of a loss in trying to understand what I should do to get this to work.

The secondary partition is an ext4 partition, and is mounted at boot-time through fstab. None of the drives are encrypted.

Interestingly, it worked fine before when I was using slightly different software. The problem only came about since upgrading to Linux Mint 19.2 (Ubuntu 18.04.3), and Apache 2.4.

Any help in solving this conundrum would be greatly appreciated. Please note that this is only a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that Linux has been built in such a way that permissions on the media directory are not to be toyed with. Instead of mounting the drive at /media/kohl/artemis, I now mount it at /mnt/artemis, and it is working.

Looking back at my logs, this is how I had it working before.